# OSGI dependent impact investigate

Tags: java, osgi

I am using `OSGI` and `google api` for my application, some libraries are not existes in google API, but when I deploy app to OSGI it throws error:

```
Unresolved requirement: Import-Package
com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.math
com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.parameterset
com.google.inject
com.google.inject.util
com.google.net.base
com.google.httputil
com.google.net.rpc
```

So I solved by import package:

```
Import-Package: \
!com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.math,
!com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.common.parameterset,\
!com.google.inject,\
!com.google.inject.util,\
!com.google.net.base,\
!com.google.httputil,\
!com.google.net.rpc,\
*
```

What's the impact to my app when I ignore these libraries?

Do you have any idea?

Comment: format and details

Answer (score 0):

The impact is that your bundle will be unable to load classes from those packages, so you will likely end up with multiple `NoClassDefFoundError` and/or `ClassNotFoundException`.